# Redirect to SPA after login with Laravel app

Tags: laravel, vue.js, authentication, single-page-application

I have two applications : SPA builded with Vuejs 3 and the api builded with Laravel. 
the SPA is running on `127.0.0.1:5173` and the api is running on `127.0.0.1:8000` 
User can authenticate successfully but I have this error thrown by the api : `404 not found` for the route `http://127.0.0.1:8000/home` and it's not redirected to another page 
I know that this is the route redirected after login in Laravel because I have this line in my `LoginController` :

```
protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;
```

and `RouteServiceProvider` is set to `/home`  
and in my `web.php` I don't have this route

My question is how I can redirect to the front-end application that can be in another url ?

the login function executed in the SPA :

```
login(data) {
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie').then((response) => {
              if (response) {
                axios
                  .post('/login', data)
                  .then((response) => {
                      console.log(response)
                      resolve(response)
                      setTimeout(() => {
                          this.loginData.email = ''
                          this.loginData.password = ''
                      }, 1000)
                  })
                  .catch((err) => {
                    reject(err)
                  })
              }
            })
          })
        },
```

.env file :

```
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=127.0.0.1:5173
SESSION_DOMAIN=127.0.0.1
```

cors.php :

```
'paths' => [
        'api/*', 
        '/login',
        '/logout',
        'sanctum/csrf-cookie'
    ],
    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
    'exposed_headers' => [],
    'max_age' => 0,
    'supports_credentials' => true,
```

sanctum.php :

```
'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', sprintf(
        '%s%s',
        'localhost,127.0.0.1:5173,localhost:3000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1',
        Sanctum::currentApplicationUrlWithPort()
    ))),
```

web.php :

```
Route::post('login', [LoginController::class, 'login']);
```

in `api.php` I have logout route and athor routes consumes by the SPA.

Comment: login should return to you api response(JSON) and if success then you will redirect from the SPA base on its routes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by passing headers in axios request and after that I redirect with vue routes :

```
axios
      .post('/login', data, {
       headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              'Accept': 'application/json',
             },
       })
     .then((response) => {
       router.push('/dashboard');
     })
```